# Check for 4 subfolders exits within a folder name variable

Tags: vba

I have a program that creates indexes every Sunday. On Sunday a folder is created named after the date with .001 suffix. The format is YYYYMMDD.001

EXAMPLE:
20130929.001

Within that folder 4 folders are created they always have the same names:
TEXT1
TEXT2
TEXT3
TEXT4

I am looking to have a script verify that the folder is being created, if one of the subfolders does not exits then an email would be sent.

The idea is to schedule the script to run on the same date but after the folder should be created. If the expected folders done exits a notification would be sent out.

My problem is dealing with the variable date the first part of the path and last part are consistent, but the date folder with the date will change every week.

N:\apps\WORLDOX\isysdb\drive_n\Text\.001\TEXT1

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks,
ELM

Comment: If you want something *scheduled* then Visual Basic for **Applications** is not what you want. VBA runs within a *hosted* platform, such as Word or Excel.

Comment: @crashmstr why could not OP use `Application.OnTime` in an Excel file, for instance?

Comment: @DavidZemens does that work when the application is not running? Either way, unless the code is actually doing something with the application domain (e.g. create or edit a Word document), then VBA does not really seem to be the right tool for the job.

Comment: @crashmstr I'd tend to agree this is not really the right tool for the job, but perhaps the only tool with which OP is familiar?  In that case, you can automate task scheduling with some VBA/VBS http://krgreenlee.blogspot.com/2006/04/excel-running-excel-on-windows-task.html

Answer (score 0):

This code checks if folder exist. If not will send a mail.

```
Sub TestFolder()

    Dim fso As Object, MyFolder As String
    Dim folder1 As String, folder2 As String, folder3 As String, folder4 As String
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    MyFolder = "C:\ YYYYMMDD.001\"

    folder1 = MyFolder & "TEXT1"
    folder2 = MyFolder & "TEXT2"
    folder3 = MyFolder & "TEXT3"
    folder4 = MyFolder & "TEXT4"

    If fso.FolderExists(folder1) = False Then
          SendMail "TEXT1"
    ElseIf fso.FolderExists(folder2) = False Then
         SendMail "TEXT2"
    ElseIf fso.FolderExists(folder3) = False Then
          SendMail "TEXT3"
    ElseIf fso.FolderExists(folder4) = False Then
          SendMail "TEXT4"
    End If


End Sub


Sub SendMail(folderName)

    Dim iMsg As Object
    Dim iConf As Object
    Dim Flds As Variant


    Set iMsg = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
    Set iConf = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")

    iConf.Load -1
    Set Flds = iConf.Fields

    With Flds
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "ddddd"
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
        .Update
    End With

    With iMsg

        Set .Configuration = iConf
        .To = "test@gmail.com"
        .From = "test@gmail.com"
        .Subject = folderName & "does not exist" & " " & Date & " " & Time
        .TextBody = folderName & "does not exist" & " " & Date & " " & Time
        .Send
    End With

    Set iMsg = Nothing
    Set iConf = Nothing

End Sub
```